# Why is FB PageTab height too small?

Tags: html, css, facebook, internet-explorer

I have a problem displaying the text using IE9 on Facebook Page Tab.

As you can see in the picture there is more text below the red box but the scroll only display it as if it was broken. By the way, if I directly go to the website and not use Facebook page tab then I can see the text I am only getting this problem when using Facebook page tab and the padding does not work.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="Content_Area">
    <div id="tab1"  >
        <p id="titlehead">Mechanics</p>
        <div id="blue-content" style="overflow-y: scroll">
            <div id="textwrap" >
                <?php
                    echo $query[0]->bco;
                    if (!empty($query[0]->gco))
                    {
                        echo $query[0]->gco;
                    }
                    echo $query[0]->hp;
                    echo "<p id = 'text'>".$query[0]->permit."</p>";
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
 #Content_Area {    
    clear:both;
    line-height:19px;
    top: 24px;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius:8px;

    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

#titlehead{
    font-family:Raspoutine-bold;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
}

#blue-content{
    width:98%;
    height: 412px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:#cceafd;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;

}

#textwrap{
    width:80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 0 0 80px 0 !important;

}
```

**Screenshot**:
[image: Screenshot of bug]

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some CSS and HTML. Further there is a FB JS SDK that allows you to fit the height dynamically.

Comment: Is the content in the actual url working good?

Comment: @Jurik i've included the html and the css

Comment: @SahilMittal yes the actual website is workign fine

Comment: And `Canvas Fixed Height` option is `NO` or `YES`?

Comment: @SahilMittal Canvas Fixed Height is set to Yes and i try setting it to No still the same problem